# Form validation in React before data goes to back-end

Tags: reactjs

I want to catch the validation errors for the form input fields before they reach the back-end. I would like to append some JSX code detailing the error message in the return statement

I can't seem to come up with a solution of iterating through the object state and giving each state an error message in this.state.formErrors   I'm also unsure how to append some JSX once the form is submitted.

```
export default class UserSignUp extends Component {

  state = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    emailAddress: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    isSignedIn: false,

    formErrors: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      password: ""
    }
  };

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();


    // I WOULD LIKE TO CATCH THE ERRORS RIGHT HERE BEFORE THE AXIOS.POST CALL AND INSERT SOME JSX IN THE RETURN STATEMENT


    if (this.state.password === this.state.confirmPassword){
      axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/users`, {
        firstName: this.state.firstName,
        lastName: this.state.lastName,
        emailAddress: this.state.emailAddress,
        password:this.state.password,
        isSignedIn: true
      }).then(() => {
        this.props.history.push('/courses');
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      });
    };
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  cancelSignUp = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push("/");
  };

  render(){
    return (
    <div className="bounds">
      <div className="grid-33 centered signin">
        <h1 className="append">Sign Up</h1>
        <div>

          <form onSubmit = {this.onSubmit}>
            <div>
              <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>


            /* I omitted the rest of this form element for clarity */
//
```

So my plan is to iterate through the state (firstName, lastName, etc.) I then want to attach a message if they are empty to the formErrors object in state. Lastly I would like to attach something like this just before my form element, if thats possible!

```
<h2 className="validation--errors--label">Validation errors</h2>
 <div className="validation-errors">
  <ul>
   <li>{this.state.formErrors.firstName}</li>
   <li>{this.state.formErrors.lastName}</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional rendering in your render method. If input was touched and is empty then it will display error. You also need to define error message for every input. Here is an example with one input:

```
    class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    touched: false
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  handleBlur = event => {
    this.setState({ touched: true });
  };

  render() {
    const { name, touched } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          value={name}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="name"
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        />
        {touched && name === "" && "Put your name please"}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that example!

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can handle form validations by yourself. But for more complex forms and its validations is usually easier to don't reinvent a wheel and use a third party package.

I personally recommend and use [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview), it's lightweight and powerful.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for future projects but for this one I would like to be able to create a simple validation from scratch